# Storing numerical values from radio button input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I'm working on an `HTML5` quiz, where I'm using radio buttons for `yes` or `no` questions, and then assigning each radio button a value of `0` or `1`, then store the numerical value as a variable, then add all the variables together to score the quiz.

**UPDATE!!!**

Hey! I made the changes you suggested, but when I call the variable, it still comes up as undefined:

Here is my html:

```
<form class="answer" id="question_one">
  <input type="radio" class="styled" name="first_answer" value="1"/><!-- POSITIVE ANSWER -->
  <div class="answer_text">Yes</div>
  <input type="radio" class="styled" name="first_answer" value="0" /><!-- NEGATIVE ANSWER -->
  <div class="answer_text">No</div>
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$('#question_one input:radio[name=first_answer]').on('change', function () {
var first_question = parseInt(
    $("input[name=first_answer]:checked").val()
    );
```

});
I tried to include a bit more specificity to the jQuery object by only targeting Radio Buttons with name=first_asnwer. Maybe I screwed up?

---

Comment: On a side note, in your HTML both inputs have 'first_answer' as the name.

Comment: @are - that's what allows them to behave as radio buttons. If there were not of the same group (defined by the name attribute) they could both be clicked and not have a toggle effect of on/off.

Comment: Well, radio buttons need to have the same name to to be mutually exclusive. That way, the user can't check Yes and No.

Comment: @are - you can see the difference [in this little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m82WF/)

Comment: Yeah sorry misunderstood his setup, I thought the second radio box was a separate answer to a question.  Seeing as the jQuery is referencing second_answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue here is the understanding of the `$(document).ready()` function.  This function is executed once all the dependencies of the page have been loaded - CSS, JavaScript, etc...

You have set your variables as soon as this function is executed which is probably before you even click on your first radio button!  The solution here would be to only calculate the values after the user has finished answering. Possibly on a change event of the radio element -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input:radio').on('change',function(){
    var $first_question = parseInt($("input[name=first_answer]:checked").val());
    var $second_question = parseInt($("input[name=second_answer]:checked").val());
    $first_question = $first_question? $first_question : 0; 
    $second_question = $second_question? $second_question : 0;
    var $total_score = $first_question + $second_question;
    alert($total_score);
  });
});
```

#### [Here is a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ETNDw/)

Comment: @are - haha... and it's a second attempt too ;)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for all the help! I made the changes you suggested, but when I call var first_question, it still comes in as undefined. I've updated the question with the new code.

Comment: @laz - You have to make sure that both groups of radio buttons actually have `:checked` values. What happened here is that when you clicked your first radio element, it tried to calculate the value of the `second_answer` as well - but that didn't have a value yet.

Comment: @laz - Check out the updates to my answer. All you need to do is make sure that the values you are adding to get the final score both exist.